# Using an iPhone as a bootable USB drive?

Tags: iphone, bootable-media

How do I use my iPhone as a bootable USB drive?

I tried [this one](http://limneoswizard.blogspot.com/2009/09/make-iphone-bootable-usb-disk-boot-your.html) but I cannot find my disk after putting `LIST DISK`. What should I do?  I hope someone would be glad to help me sort out this problem of mine because I cannot afford to buy an USB disk at the moment and my operating system is dying.

Comment: sounds like a bad idea

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone doesn't behave like a flash drive. DFU mode doesn't do the trick so the only way is to **jailbreak** it and find a program to do so. I have **netatalk** on my iPhone 4, which is a AFP (Apple File Protocol) fileserver and wireless. I love it and it is seen by all Macs in Finder when the iPhone is connected to the WIFI network. Also you can transfer files with Linux and Windows, but you might need to download software to access the AFP server

Answer (score 1):

I know a way you can make it.

1. Make sure that your iPhone is jailbroken and that you have a section of its memory sectioned off as USB storage. Instructions for how to accomplish this can be found in the References section, if it isn't already done. Plug the iPhone into your computer. Once the iPhone loads, your computer should read it as a drive, which will show up with all your other drives.
2. Open an Internet window and go to: http://www.datafilehost.com/download-a717212e.html. This is where you download the necessary software for a Windows setup that you can use as a boot disc. Download this software and save it in the partitioned section of your iPhone that is acting as a USB drive.
3. Copy the files from your iPhone onto a computer that needs to be booted. Essentially, your iPhone is now just a USB that's carrying boot disc information in it's separated section. Rather than simply popping in the CD; however, you need to plug your iPhone into the computer you're going to boot, access the drive, and then download the files.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't try messing with the boot sector of your iPhone.

If you mean you just want it as storage then read this [forum post](http://www.mactalk.com.au/31/57450-how-use-iphone-usb-mass-storage-file-viewer.html) to get some info on diskaid.